# wxPython ObjectListView Capture Ctrl-C shortcut

Tags: wxpython, py2exe, objectlistview

I am having difficulty with my program written in Python 2.7.5 using wxPython 2.9.5, ObjectListView 1.2, lxml 2.3, and SQLAlchemy 0.8.2 and compiled into an exe with py2exe.

The problem I am running into is after compiling the program into an exe I am no longer able to use Ctrl-C to copy data from the ObjectListView and paste it into other programs such as Excel, Notepad, or even Notepad++. This happens regardless of how many rows are selected to be copy/pasted. The results I get when pasting into Excel is "Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data." and when I try notepad I get the very first letter from the first column and row (I think it is the first row) but nothing else.

Here is a code snippet from one of the output windows I am having the issues with (there are 2 total, but they are almost perfect mirrors of each other). This is imported by the main script and then added to an agw AUI Notebook as a page.

```
import wx
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import ectworker as EW

TabLabel = 'Primary Output'
outputOne = []

class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        headerFont = wx.Font(12, wx.MODERN, wx.SLANT, wx.NORMAL)
        title = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " Primary Output:")
        title.SetFont(headerFont)

        self.countDisplay = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '%s'%len(invOutput))
        self.countDisplay.SetFont(headerFont)

        self.dataOLV = ObjectListView(self, wx.ID_ANY,
            style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.setColumns()
        self.dataOLV.SetEmptyListMsg('Please click the show button.\n\
            If nothing appears then there is nothing to display')
        self.dataOLV.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_NONE

        updateBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Show')
        updateBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updateControl)

        filterBtn = wx.Button(self, label='Filter')
        filterBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.filterInfo)

        lookupBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Look Up')
        lookupBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onLookUp)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox0 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox0.Add(title, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox0.Add(self.countDisplay, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox1.Add(updateBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox1.Add(filterBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox1.Add(lookupBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox.Add(hbox0, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vbox.Add(self.dataOLV, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)

    def setColumns(self, data=None):
        self.idColumn = ColumnDefn('Dealer ID', 'left', -1, 'id')
        self.nameColumn = ColumnDefn('Dealer Name', 'left', -1, 'name')
        self.thirdColumn = ColumnDefn('Third', 'left', -1, 'third')
        self.fourthColumn = ColumnDefn('Fourth', 'left', -1, 'fourth')
        self.fifthColumn = ColumnDefn('Fifth', 'left', -1, 'fifth')
        self.sixthColumn = ColumnDefn('Sixth', 'right', -1, 'sixth')
        self.seventhColumn = ColumnDefn('Seventh', 'right', -1, 'seventh')
        self.olvColumns = [
            self.idColumn,
            self.nameColumn,
            self.thirdColumn,
            self.fourthColumn,
            self.fifthColumn,
            self.sixthColumn,
            self.seventhColumn]

        self.dataOLV.SetColumns(self.olvColumns)

    def updateControl(self, event):
        outputOne = EW.filterOne()
        self.updateOLV(outputOne)        

    def filterInfo(self, event):
        pub.sendMessage('dialog.filter', event=None)
        while EW.dataVars.theFilter == []:
            pub.sendMessage('dialog.filter', event=None)
        outputOne = EW.filterOne()
        self.updateOLV(outputOne)

    def updateOLV(self, object):
        self.dataOLV.SetObjects(object)
        self.countDisplay.SetLabel('%s'%len(object))

    def onLookUp(self, event):
      # This needs proper error handling
        selectedRow = self.dataOLV.GetSelectedObject()
        try:
            webbrowser.open('sc/%s' % selectedRow.id)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('File file is not meant to be run as a stand alone application.')
    print('  Please try again by running the main program.')
```

My primary question is how can I get the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+C to properly function after compiling with py2exe?

Before I receive the responses of "Try PyInstaller", I have and I receive an error message each time, but that is for another possible question posting.

Thanks in advance.

--EDIT--

I thought this code would be my solution, however my final result is a jumbled mash-up of foreign languages.

```
def onCtrlC(self, event):
    selectedRows = self.dataOLV.GetSelectedObjects()
    self.dataObj = wx.TextDataObject()
    self.dataObj.SetData('%s'%str(selectedRows))
    if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
        wx.TheClipboard.SetData(self.dataObj)
        wx.TheClipboard.Flush()
    else:
        pub.sendMessage('dialog.error', message='Unable to open the clipboard',
                        caption='Error')
```

I'm making an educated guess that I am missing something.

--EDIT2--

Got it working as desired, thanks to Mike Driscoll, thank you!
I did change how I was putting the data into the clipboard, I don't think it is the most efficient, but it works. I also discovered why I was receiving a jumbled mess when pasting. Code is below, I am using a multiline TextCtrl to temporarily store the data and clearing it when I am done.

```
self.hiddenTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
self.hiddenTxt.Hide()

def onCtrlC(self, event):
    selectedRows = self.dataOLV.GetSelectedObjects()
    for x in selectedRows:
        self.hiddenTxt.AppendText('%s\t%s\n'%(x.id, x.name))
    self.dataObj = wx.TextDataObject()
    self.dataObj.SetText(self.hiddenTxt.GetValue())
    if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
        wx.TheClipboard.SetData(self.dataObj)
        wx.TheClipboard.Flush()
    else:
        pub.sendMessage('dialog.error', message='Unable to open the clipboard',
                        caption='Error')
    self.hiddenTxt.SetValue('')
```

The part I goofed on was:

```
    self.dataObj.SetData
```

It actually needed to be:

```
    self.dataObj.SetText
```

By using \t between the tidbits on each line I am able to paste into Excel with no issues at all!

Many, Many thanks to you Mike D.

Comment: I would change the data object into a comma separated list or a string with commas in it to fake a comma separated list. Then add the list or string to the ClipBoard

Comment: @MikeD Thank you, I did try comma separated however I still ran into issues pasting into Excel, but I was able to paste into Excel with no issues using \t instead. I also noticed that I was using SetData instead of SetText when adding the text to the dataObj, which appears to have been the cause for my multilingual output.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the clipboard explicitly to make this work. I don't know why you would, but that's my first thought. Here are a couple of tutorials on the subject:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/05/25/wxpython-how-to-use-the-clipboard/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ClipBoard

I would also ask on the wxPython users list / Google group. A lot of developers hang out there and may be able to give you additional pointers:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wxpython-users

Comment: Thank you for the rapid reply, I will definitely take a look at those link and check with the wxPython user list/Google group. It just stumps me as to why copy/paste works properly when run as a script through Python, but not after using py2exe to create a Windows exe. My first thought was that py2exe may be skewing things. Again though I will definitely look into working with the clipboard explicitly. Any suggestions on "capturing" the Ctrl+C key combination and binding it to a function that would copy to the clipboard?

Comment: Yeah, that is weird. I totally agree with you there. As for catching key combinations, I recommend creating an Accelerator Table. I wrote about those here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/

Comment: I was able to use an accelerator table to capture the Ctrl+C key combination, and technically copy the contents of the selected rows into the system clipboard. However, pasting that data has yielded some "odd" results. The pasted data is an incoherent mess. I've added the code to my original question,